# Why is the syllable division for glorious "glo-ri-ous" rather than "glor-i-ous"?

Tags: hyphenation, syllables

https://www.howmanysyllables.com/syllables/glorious

**Divide glorious into syllables:   glo-ri-ous**

Why is it glo-ri-ous and not glor-i-ous? And shouldn't "glo" be pronounced as glow?

Which syllable division rule is used here?

Comment: If you were singing the 5th line of the National Anthem, would you sing "glor" including the "r" on a single note, or would you sing "ri" on the note following? Also note that division into syllables does not change the pronunciation.

Comment: Timathion: what makes you think that https://www.howmanysyllables.com/syllables/glorious is correct?

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glorious) seems to differ between its syllabification and its pronunciation guide, if I read it correctly, so it's probably a judgment call.

Comment: It's often difficult to determine which syllable the consonant that connects syllables belongs to, and dictionaries make arbitrary choices, often following a rule of thumb like the consonant belongs to the following syllable.

Comment: @Greybeard Yes, the syllabificaton and pronuciation are hypenated differently in M-W: glo·​ri·​ous vs \ ˈglȯr-ē-əs\. With the answer from Peter Shor, I take it as that the syllabification is out of date while the pronunciation changed over time.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is causing some confusion, but please note that breaks for hyphenation and for syllabification are often different: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/word-division-dots-and-syllable-pronunciation-hyphens

Comment: @Peter: the division into syllables may not determine the pronunciation, but the pronunciation does determine the division into syllables. Consider the word [present](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/present).

Comment: @PeterShor Knuth says you should not hyphenate *present* at all.

Comment: @tchrist: the reason he doesn't hyphenate present is that his software is unable to decide whether present is a verb (pre-sent) or a noun (pres-ent). If you're hyphenating manually, you shouldn't hesitate to put a hyphen in the proper place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syllabifications from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glorious), which it seems like the program you link to uses, were settled upon over 100 years ago and most of them haven't been updated when the pronunciations changed.

In English, a syllable is generally not hyphenated after a vowel if it's a lax vowel or an r-influenced vowel.

Why are *coral* and *floral* hyphenated cor·​al and flo·​ral? Because in the 19th century, these words were pronounced<sup>1</sup> [core-al](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Webster_s_High_School_Dictionary/CMAWAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=cope) and [floe-ral](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Webster_s_High_School_Dictionary/CMAWAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=flow), as you can see by looking at the 1892 Webster's High School Dictionary (linked to from those words). Today, Americans no longer distinguish the vowels [o] and [ɔ] before an /r/, and Merriam-Webster's pronunciation shows that *coral* and *floral* rhyme.

In the 19th century, as you can see from that dictionary, *glorious* was pronounced with the vowel of *floral*, and not of *coral*. So it was hyphenated after the o.

<sup>1</sup> at least by the people who Webster thought mattered.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. So the syllabification as **glo-ri-ous** is correct since the pronunciation **gloe-rious** exists, but it is not updated as the pronunciation changed over time.

Comment: @Timathon The pronunciation "gloe-rious" only exists in American English. In British English it is glo[r]-ri-ous as the "o" is pronounced **[ɔ:]** as in "for".

Comment: @Graybeard: I'm not at all sure the pronunciation "gloe-rious" is ever still used in American English. It's certainly not used in General American or in any Northeast accent I'm aware of. But if you believe 19th century dictionaries (I checked another one), it was the accepted pronunciation, at least among East Coast educated people, in the 19th century.

Comment: The syllabification has nothing to do with how the first vowel is pronounced.

Comment: @siride: This is incorrect. In English, (1) a syllable generally is not broken after a lax vowel, and (2) syllables ending with r-influenced vowels are generally broken after the r.

Comment: @siride: do you have any evidence for your claim? Here's my evidence: [na-vel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/navel), [rav-el](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravel), and [grav-el](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gravel) are hyphenated differently. If the first vowel doesn't have anything to do with this, why aren't they all the same?

Comment: @PeterShor Choral (hehe, cho-ral) contexts often emphasize the separation of the "r" from the vowel, even in the US. I play Handel's Messiah every year, and the directors are always yelling at the choir to sing "And the glahw-ree." So, granted, it's not "glow," but the point is it's not "glorrrr".

Comment: By the vowel [o] do you mean the vowel in "floe"? If so, then do these Americans rhyme "low-rate" with "borate"? and "toe-ring" with "boring"? If not, then what do you mean by the vowel [o] before an /r/?

Comment: If you want pronunciations from Merriam-Webster, use their [online pronouncing dictionary](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater). Hyphenation, on the other hand, is not official in any way, so do whatever makes sense to you that your wordprocessor will let you get away with.

Comment: @RosieF: These vowels were distinguished 130 years ago; *for* did not rhyme with *four*. I don't know the exact vowels people used, although I think *toe-ring* would at least have been pretty close to *boring*. This distinction is pretty much dead in America, although it is still preserved in the traditional Boston accent (also slowly dying) where *for* rhymes with *flaw* and *four* rhymes with *boa*, but presumably in Webster's pronunciation the /r/s weren't dropped, so this doesn't really indicate how the words were pronounced back then.

Comment: I still think people here are completely confusing the typesetting concept of where to put hyphens if you have to break a word with actual pronunciations. The hyphens do not show pronunciation. They only tell you how to type something. Using Knuth's algorithm from TeX, you **should** hyphenate *flo-ral* and *glo-ri-ous* but you should never hyphenate *coral* at all because it breaks the rules about what can be left by itself. This only reflects typesetting, nothing else.

Comment: @tchrist: somebody at some point decided where to put the hyphens. They did it based on pronunciation during the 19th century, and it hasn't been revised. So English hyphenation is two centuries less out of date than English spelling, but there are still cases where neither of them makes any sense.